# how to get components and search csv file

Tags: c++, csv, search, line

int main()
{

```
struct tokens : std::ctype<char>
{
    tokens() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        typedef std::ctype<char> cctype;
        static const cctype::mask *const_rc = cctype::classic_table();

        static cctype::mask rc[cctype::table_size];
        std::memcpy(rc, const_rc, cctype::table_size * sizeof(cctype::mask));

        rc['/'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc['$'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

std::string FormatMsg = "AB/LK$VD$SA$PO";
cin >> FormatMsg;
std::stringstream ss(FormatMsg);
ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new tokens()));
std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
std::vector<std::string> vstrings(begin, end);
std::copy(vstrings.begin(), vstrings.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));


system("Pause");
```

}

From this code I want to get AB, LK and SA and look for similar components from separate CSV files.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This questions cries for `std::regex`.

You can search for patterns, match patterns or iterate over patterns.

And this can be used for splitting the string.

C++ has, since long, a build in and dedicated functionality, specifically designed for this purpose, to tokenize strings (split strings into tokens). And because such a simple dedicated function, designed for this purpose, is available, it simply should be used. There is no need for external libraries or complicated constructs. Simply use the `std::sregex_token_iterator`.

This is an iterator (like many other iterators), that iterates over tokens (sub-strings) of a string. So, what we want.

We can then use the `std::vector`s range constructor to write something simple like this:

```
std::vector tokens(std::sregex_token_iterator(msg.begin(), msg.end(), delimiter, -1), {}));
```

So, we define a variable with the name "tokens" of type `std::vector` (with CTAD the type of the vector is automatically deduced). We use its range constructor and provide a begin and an end iterator. The begin iterator is the `std::sregex_token_iterator` and the end-iterator is its default-initialized counterpart. Simply `{}`.

To put such a vector into a 2D Vector, we use an outer vectors `emplace_back` function and do an inplace construction for the inner vector.

So you read the whole CSV-File with 2 statements

- a simple for loop
- a simple emplace back with the `std::sregex_token_iterator`

```
        // We will read all lines of the source file with a simple for loop and std::getline
        for (std::string msg{}; std::getline(csvFile, msg); ) {

            // We will split the one big string into tokens (sub-strings) and add it to our 2D array
            csvData.emplace_back(std::vector<std::string>(std::sregex_token_iterator(msg.begin(), msg.end(), delimiter, -1), {}));
        }
```

That was the theory. Practically it means that for your case you only need to define a variable tokens and use its constructor. There is no additional statement needed. We have a typical one liner.

Your code would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// Slash and $ are the delimiters
std::regex delimiter{ R"(\/|\$)" };

int main() {

    // The test data
    std::string msg = "AB/LK$VD$SA$PO";

    // Defining the variable token and initialize it using its range constructor
    std::vector tokens(std::sregex_token_iterator(msg.begin(), msg.end(), delimiter, -1), {});

    // Show result on the screen
    std::copy(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

The description of the source file is not very detailed. I do not know the structure of your CSV data.

If there are other strings in a different format, you can add a `std::regex_match` function with a `std::regex` like this: `^[A-Z]{2}\/[A-Z]{2}((\$[A-Z]{2})+)$`. But this all depends on the format of your strings.

Of course you can adapt your regexes and they will give you back whatever you want.